# Play framework check out from SVN missing sbt libs

Tags: svn, version-control, playframework

I have created a play framework application on my work computer. I added the source to a SVN repository. I got this repository code on my home computer. When I run play command it gives me the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/StringContext
    at sbt.CommandStrings$.<init>(CommandStrings.scala:62)
    at sbt.CommandStrings$.<clinit>(CommandStrings.scala)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.initialize(Main.scala:195)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:27)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:55)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$explicit$1.apply(Launch.scala:45)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:69)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.StringContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/StringContext
```

I've tried everything shy of creating a new app and migrating all code to this new app.. I'm assuming that either there was a setting before I committed my code that I missed or there is a play command I'm missing to make it work on my new computer.

Now I know that the problem is that I'm missing the libs from SBT in the play project. If I check intellij external libs, on my work email there is a slew of SBT libs, where as at my home location there is 0.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please paste your build.sbt (if present) and all files in the "project" folder.

Answer (score 1):

Play distributive path (PATH variable) should be updated.
Make sure Play Framework 2.2.x is downloaded.

Also close all previously opened 'command prompt' windows and then execute 'play clean' command

Comment: The error is caused by compiling your webapp with the wrong version of play.